# SQL Translator (SQLFairy) - 'Invalid statement: Was expecting comment, or use, or set, or drop'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, erd

**Environment**

Fedora 19 and MariaDB on VirtualBox in Windows 7

**Installation**

`yum install perl-SQL-Translator`

**Steps**

Generate dump with:

```
[username@hostname ~] mysqldump -u root -pmysql_root_password database_name > example.sql
```

Generate diagram with:

```
[username@hostname ~]  sqlt-graph -f MySQL -o example.png -t png example.sql
```

**Error**

```
ERROR (line 36): Invalid statement: Was expecting comment, 
or use, or set, or drop, or create, or alter, or insert, or 
delimiter, or empty statement
Error: translate: Error with parser 'SQL::Translator::Parser::MySQL':  
no results at /usr/bin/sqlt-graph line 195.
```

**Links**

[SQLFairy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlfairy/)

**Edit**

Error also occurs in the following SQL on line 5:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `my_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
LOCK TABLES `test_table` WRITE;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this would be that you export only your table defintions of your schema. The error in your example should btw. not occur on line five but on line six where the table gets locked for inserting data.

As a solution dump your schema without the data, given your example above you can do the following to get a dump which is working with the fairy:

```
mysqldump -u root -pmysql_root_password --no-data database_name > example.sql
```

Comment: That worked, thank you, I wondered if it was something like that but hadn't seen it come up in the documentation, thank you.

Comment: Adding `--compatible=ansi` might be also helpful when `--no-data` is not enough.